# Ext 4.2.1 Model date parsing inconsistent across browsers

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

I have declared a Model in Ext JS 4.2.1 with type "date"

I'm inserting a record with value "2016-04-07 22:46:15.000"

In Chrome, the value is parsed (and displayed) correctly.
In IE11 and Firefox, the value is silently dropped from the record.

I have a minimal example here:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

Ext.define('Customer', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ { name:'contract_start', type:'date'} ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'customerStore',
    model:'Customer',
    data:{'items':[
        { 'contract_start': "2016-04-07 22:46:15.000" }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('customerStore'),
    columns: [
        { dataIndex: 'contract_start', flex: 1 }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: 'target'
});


});
```

[JS Fiddle | https://jsfiddle.net/jnj3j7r2/]

Is this a known bug in Ext JS 4.2.1?
Are there any known work arounds, or anything to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's covered in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-dateFormat):

> It is quite important to note that while this config is optional, it
>   will default to using the base JavaScript Date object's parse function
>   if not specified, rather than Ext.Date.parse. This can cause
>   unexpected issues, especially when converting between timezones, or
>   when converting dates that do not have a timezone specified. The
>   behavior of the native Date.parse is implementation-specific, and
>   depending on the value of the date string, it might return the UTC
>   date or the local date. For this reason it is strongly recommended
>   that you always specify an explicit date format when parsing dates.

Comment: so the work around is: `, dateFormat:'c'` in the Field declaration